Does SignalR (or websocket) can send concurrent message on single connection?
I want to send multiple data back to client concurrently on single connection.
I just want to know does on a single SignalR connection (or websocket), can the data transmission on single connection can be send concurrent or we need multiple connection to achieve this?
Thank you!

Depends on how you implement. You can split the data into fragments etc but by default it’s just data messages one after another. What would you need concurrency for?

Hi @SamiKuhmonen, thank you for your help. From one client, I want to call multiple methods on hub to get data, and I want to limit the connection to 1 only, for now server can handle multiple requests from one connection, but if when here have one already sent
large data (lasting 1 minute), so it blocks all others from that connection. Therefore, I need to verify if there is a way to send concurrently over just one connection.

Only by manually chopping it to blocks or something. SignalR might not be the best way to handle such long time data transfers

Hi @SamiKuhmonen, thank you for your help.  I understand that SignalR wasn't specifically designed for sending large amounts of data, but I've been using it to send data back to the client after completing a long-running task without forcing the client to wait. With HTTP, the connection needs to wait during that time, and there have a timeout.

I understand that I should use SignalR to notify the client when the task is completed, and then have the client make an HTTP call to retrieve the data. However, I'm unsure how to implement this approach. Would creating a link for the client to call be the right way to go about it? I would greatly appreciate your advice. Thank you!
